# "music emerge" or "music emerges"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if need to add an *s* at the end of the word.

> We are sound and silence, together creating voices and music emerge(**s**).

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/gjFFEY8hf5w) at 4 minute and 33 second, and the verb without an *s*. I know that the word music is uncountable, and that is plural, but should it not be treated as singular?

Comment: Yeah, it's just an oddly structured sentence.  It's possible the narrator misread the story, and either didn't realize it, or didn't care to go back and re-record that section.  I wouldn't over-think it though.  Just write it off as a mistake of some kind and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it is uncountable and requires the singular verb **emerges**.

However, **music** is not plural.

Although some nouns such as **air** can be used in the plural in certain contexts (to put on airs) I am struggling to think of a context in which one could speak of **musics**.

All varieties of music, no matter how many or varied, are all just **music** and never **musics**.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a weird sentence, but if you parse it differently:

> together creating, (voices and music) emerge

where *voices* is one noun phrase and *voices and music* is a larger plural noun phrase, and neither is a direct object of *creating* - then *emerge* makes sense as a plural verb form.

Actually - while listening to the clip, I hear a pause after the word *voices* so maybe this is not the correct interpretation (unless the narrator is reading the script incorrectly).

Maybe *creating voices* and *music* are the two noun phrases? I am not sure what a *creating voice* is, though. The sentence is odd either way.